# RDP with windows 8 client to windows 7 enterprise to only 2 of my 3 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Title pretty much says it all.  I have 3 monitors and I want to keep one out of the RDP scope so that I can have some local windows up.

Is it possible to specify which monitors I want the RDP connection to use somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way the Remote Desktop applet works, this currently isn't possible if you wish to remain Full Screen. You can however make the session appear in "windowed mode" and drag it to however many monitors you want.

To do this:
Open Remote Desktop > Click "Options" in the bottom left corner > Select the "Display" Tab > Change the drag bar from "Full Screen" to another Dimension". > Launch Remote Desktop.